# Using data-i8n with dynamic parms

Tags: jquery, json, i18next

I can use [data-18n](http://i18next.com/pages/doc_jquery.html) no problem with a json properties file like this:

```
<div data-i18n="errIncorrectSpecies"></div>
```

json properties file has this entry:

```
"errIncorrectSpecies":"You have selected incorrect species tests."
```

How I go about putting dynamic params into the "errIncorrectSpecies" value?  I would like to do this in my json file:

```
"errIncorrectSpecies":"You have selected {0} tests for this {1}."
```

Just not sure how to pass in "{0}" and "{1}"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I can do it like this in my html file...

```
<div>{{i18n('errIncorrectSpecies', {'0':'test','1':'test2'})}}</div>
```

I'm going to see if I can do this programmatically in my angular directive instead of in the HTML.